# Failing to use collections

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 columns with 7 rows of numbers in each.
My code is supposed to:

1. Identify which column I selected
2. Get all numbers from one of the columns I didnt select and add to a collection (In order. This is important)
3. Get all numbers from the column I selected and add them to the collection (Also in order)
4. Get all numbers from the remaining column and add it to the collection.
5. In order, from first column to last, from first row to last, place the items that were inside the collection

However, it seems that every time it gets some kind of random order.

It is my first time using collections. Can anyone spot what I did wrong?

Sample data

[image: Sample Data]

What should happen

[image: What should happen]

What actually happens

[image: What actually happens]

And of course, the culprit

```
Option Explicit
Public vez As Long
Public grupo As New Collection

Sub magic(coluna As Long)
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim i As Long
Set grupo = Nothing
If vez < 3 Then
    If coluna = 1 Then
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 2)
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 1)
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 3)
        Next row
    ElseIf coluna = 2 Then
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 1)
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 2)
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 3)
        Next row
    ElseIf coluna = 3 Then
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 2)
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 3)
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo.Add Cells(row, 1)
        Next row
    End If
    i = 1
    For row = 1 To 7
        For col = 1 To 3
            Cells(row, col) = grupo.Item(i)
            i = i + 1
        Next col
    Next row
    vez = vez + 1
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a `Cell` to the `Collection`, but I think you really want to add the Cell's `Value` (so that it rewrites using the value that was in the cell when you added it to the collection, rather than writing out the value that is in the cell when you are writing it to the new location).

```
Option Explicit
Public vez As Long
Public grupo As New Collection

Sub magic(coluna As Long)
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set grupo = Nothing
    If vez < 3 Then
        If coluna = 1 Then
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 2).Value
            Next row
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 1).Value
            Next row
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 3).Value
            Next row
        ElseIf coluna = 2 Then
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 1).Value
            Next row
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 2).Value
            Next row
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 3).Value
            Next row
        ElseIf coluna = 3 Then
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 2).Value
            Next row
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 3).Value
            Next row
            For row = 1 To 7
                grupo.Add Cells(row, 1).Value
            Next row
        End If
        i = 1
        For row = 1 To 7
            For col = 1 To 3
                Cells(row, col).Value = grupo.Item(i)
                i = i + 1
            Next col
        Next row
        vez = vez + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Default properties strike again! Nice answer.

Comment: And that works! Yea.. thank you! I replaced it with arrays and it worked, but that wouldn't be the right answer to my question, right?

Comment: @Moacir - Using arrays caused Excel to think "I need to put a `Range` object such as `Cells(row, 2)` into a `String` variable.  I can't do that, I will need to do the next best thing.  I will use the `Value` of the `Range` object because it can be converted to `String`."  All of us become complacent about explicitly specifying `Value` when we mean to use it, knowing that Excel will usually implicitly use it, but we forget that in some cases a Type conversion is not going to happen.

Comment: @YowE3K It was a really good explanation. As I mentioned in the question, it was my first time using a collection. I've heard about it and decided to use it to test it. The first thing that came to my mind was an old magic trick that involves 21 cards and 3 columns. Now I have a "magic" worksheet :)

Comment: @Moacir - I assume "Pick a number, press the button at the bottom of the column.  Now find it again and press the button at the bottom of the column it is now in.  And again.  Is your number ... (value in cell B4)?"

Comment: If you click on the button all the 3 times it allows, it will actually be always on cell B4, but its exactly like that. Next step is to make this organized on code but all mixed up when it displays to the user.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For my next magic trick I'm going to make all those `For row = 1 To 7` dissapear

### Alakazam!!!!

```
Option Explicit
Public vez As Long
Public grupo As New Collection

Sub magic(coluna As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range, Source As Range
    Set Source = Range(Choose(coluna, "B1:B7,A1:A7,C1:C7", "A1:A7,B1:B7,C1:C7", "B1:B7,C1:C7,A1:A7"))
    Set grupo = New Collection
    For Each c In Source
        grupo.Add c.Value
    Next

    For Each c In Source
        grupo.Add c.Value
    Next

    For Each c In Range("A1:C7")
        i = i + 1
        c.Value = grupo.Item(i)
    Next

    vez = vez + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Check @YowE3K answer. It works perfectly with collections instead of arrays.

Replaced collections with an array. Arrays seems easier to work.

```
Option Explicit
Public vez As Long


Sub magic(coluna As Long)
Dim grupo(1 To 21) As String
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim i As Long
i = 1
If vez < 2 Then
    If coluna = 1 Then
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 3).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
    ElseIf coluna = 2 Then
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 3).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
    ElseIf coluna = 3 Then
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 2).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 3).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
        For row = 1 To 7
            grupo(i) = Cells(row, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
        Next row
    End If
    i = 1
    For row = 1 To 7
        For col = 1 To 3
            Cells(row, col).Value = grupo(i)
            i = i + 1
        Next col
    Next row
    vez = vez + 1
End If
End Sub
```

Now it works as intended.

Comment: Beware though: if your array was a `Variant` array, it's quite possible that you would be having the exact same problem, if not worse (because a `Range` can implicitly be converted to a 2D array, so that could become an array of arrays). The real fix is to say what you mean, and mean what you say: if you mean `Cells(row, n).Value`, then write that. Don't write code that relies on default properties and implicit conversions.

Comment: I wrote this before I saw YowE3k answer. I'll fix this code and leave it here for the future in case someone stumble with this.

Comment: Will check. Thanks!